# By Value By Reference -- mutable immutable copy.deepcopy

Tags: python

please enlighten me as I'm confused

```
    import copy

    class Fee:
        E = {'e':'e'}

    class Fii:
        Data = copy.deepcopy(Fee().E)

    class Fuu:
        Data = Fee.E

    Fuu.Data
```

As expected {'e': 'e'}

```
    Fii.Data
```

As expected {'e': 'e'}

Lets change Fuu.Data['e'] to 'g'

```
    Fuu.Data['e'] = 'g'
```

and Check

```
    Fii.Data
```

As expected {'e': 'e'}

```
    Fuu.Data
```

As expected {'e': 'g'}

change back

```
    Fuu.Data['e'] = 'e'
```

and check

```
    Fii.Data

    Fuu.Data
```

As expected

a combined Class

```
    class FiiFuu:
        Data1 = copy.deepcopy(Fii())
        Data2 = Fuu()
```

Some Dict

```
    Dev={}
```

populate the Dict

```
    Dev['def'] = FiiFuu()
    Dev['new'] = FiiFuu()
```

check Values in Dict

```
    Dev['def'].Data1.Data
```

As expected {'e': 'e'}

```
    Dev['def'].Data2.Data
```

As expected{'e': 'e'}

```
    Dev['new'].Data1.Data
```

As expected{'e': 'e'}

```
    Dev['new'].Data2.Data
```

As expected {'e': 'e'}

Change some Value

```
    Dev['new'].Data1.Data['e']='g'
```

and check

```
    Dev['new'].Data1.Data
```

As expected {'e': 'g'}
But

```
    Dev['def'].Data1.Data
```

Yields also {'e': 'g'}

## WHY?

with kind regards
Martin

Comment: Can you share what you got for `Dev['def'].Data1.Data` and why it confuses you?

Comment: It's because you're defining your class fields as static. It doesn't matter how many instances of `FiiFuu` you create because `Data1` and `Data2` belong to the class, not the instance, so even though `Dev["def"]` and `Dev["new"]` are separate instances, changing the _static field_ will affect the whole class.

Comment: Rather than "static field", in Python we call this a *class attribute*.

Comment: OP: it's hard to understand the question because you go through a lot of steps and most of them you label the result as expected. Please try to focus on a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and be clear about 1) what happens when you run the code; 2) what you think should happen instead, and why you think that should happen.

Comment: @rchome -- edited to include Answer

Comment: @hyper-neutrino -- Got It!  But this leads to the question of how to decouple it.

Comment: @ Karl Knechtel @hyper-neutrino  https://python-course.eu/oop/class-instance-attributes.php pointed me in the right direction.